# java.lang.NullPointerException within a GA

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm doing my Final year project using a Genetic Algorithm to design a set of time tables for my college.

I'm running into 1 error that is stopping me from moving forward. I'm getting the following errors.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at LunchTimeFree.calculateViolations(LunchTimeFree.java:36)
at FitnessFunction.calculateFitnesScore(FitnessFunction.java:34)
at Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

This isn't making any sense to me though: At that line is this line of code:

```
    int time = c.genes[i].time;
```

It's set the variable time to the time value of a certain gene within my chromosome.
I've debugged it and inserted a println statement after printing my time variable and the c.genes[i].time variable and they are both initialized to variables, i.e time = 1 or 2 etc.

I don't understand what the problem is. Please can someone help me?!

```
public class LunchTimeFree extends constraintInterface {

    Chromosome c;

    public LunchTimeFree(Chromosome chromo){
        c = chromo;
    }

    @Override
    public double calculateViolations() {     
    double violations=0;    

    int i = 0; 
    int y = c.getLength();

    while(i <= y-1 )
    {
        int time = c.genes[i].time;

        if (time >= 16 && time <= 25)   {                           
            violations = violations + 1;        
                            } 
                i++;
    }      

    return violations*this.weight;

    }
}
```

---

```
public class ChromosomeFactory
{

Chromosome c;

 public ChromosomeFactory(int l)
 {

 c = new Chromosome(l);

 DummyDatabase da = new DummyDatabase();

 int numOfLectures = da.GetNumLectures();

  int i=0;

  while(i<=numOfLectures-1)
   {

   int lecture = da.getLecture(i);   

   int r = da.Rooms[(int)(Math.random() * da.Rooms.length)];
   int t = da.TimeSlots[(int)(Math.random() * da.TimeSlots.length)]; 

   Gene g = new Gene(lecture,lecture,r,t);

    c.genes[i] = g;
           System.out.println(""+this.c.genes[i].teacher+","+this.c.genes[i].lecture+","+this.c.genes[i].room+","+this.c.genes[i].time+"");
    i++;
    }
   }  
   }

 public class FitnessFunction 
{
Chromosome c;

public FitnessFunction(Chromosome newChromo)  {
    c = newChromo;
}

public double calculateFitnesScore() {

    LunchTimeFree ltf = new LunchTimeFree(c);

    ltf.setWeight(0.01);

    double violationScore =ltf.calculateViolations();

    double score = (1/(1 + violationScore));

    return score;

  }
```

---

```
 public class Chromosome 
 {

Gene[] genes;



public Chromosome(int l)
{
genes = new Gene[l]; 

}

public int getLength()
{
return genes.length;
}



}
```

---

```
public class Gene 
{
public int teacher;
public int lecture;
public int room;
public int time;


public Gene(int t,int l, int r, int time)
{

this.teacher=t;    
this.lecture=l;
this.room=r;
this.time=time;

}



}
```

---

```
public class DummyDatabase implements DatabaseAccessor
{

 int[] Lecturers = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
  int[] Lectures = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19} ;

  int[] TimeSlots =      {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55};

    int[] Rooms = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};





@Override
public int GetRoom(int entry) {

    return this.Rooms[entry];
}

@Override
public int GetNumLectures() {
    return this.Lectures.length;
}

@Override
public int getTeacher(int entry) {
    return this.Lecturers[entry];
}

@Override
public int getLecture(int entry) {
    return this.Lectures[entry];
}

@Override
public int getNumRooms() {
    return this.Rooms.length;
}
```

}

Comment: The problem is either `c` or `genes[i]` is null.  We'd have to see that snippet of code to tell you which it is, though.

Comment: What code would you want to see?

Comment: I'm on GitHub if any1 wants to look at it through that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: Splitting

```
int time = c.genes[i].time;
```

into

```
final Gene[] allGenes = c.genes;
final Gene aGene = allGenes[i];
final int time = aGene.time;
```

should show you exactly which of the references is null in the stacktrace. That may help to narrow down the location of the bug.

Apart from that maybe a long call, but all else in your posted code looks ok:

Does `getLength` in your Chromosome class return the length of the `genes` array? Or the number of set genes in the array? If the genes array is not fully filled and `getLength` indicates the (incorrect) number of filled array slots the while loop may overshoot and hit a null in the array. Note that you use the int variable `l` as constructor argument for a Chromosome in the ChromosomeFactory, but fill the genes array up to `numOfLectures`. If `l` is used to set the size of the gene array in Chromosome and `l` and `numOfLectures` differ you may have a problem. The difference will be filled with nulls in the array.

```
int y = c.getLength();
while(i <= y-1 )
{
    int time = c.genes[i].time;
    if (time >= 16 && time <= 25)   {                           
        violations = violations + 1;        
    } 
    i++;
}
```

Also consider replacing that with a for-loop like

```
for (int i = 0; i < c.getLength(); i++) {
   int time = c.genes[i].time;
   if (time >= 16 && time <= 25) {                           
      violations++;   
   }
}
```

For loops should be preferred, as they minimize the scope of loop variables, handle the increasing of loop variables and are easier to grasp. Also consider using one of the Collection classes instead of an array. And **strongly** consider changing all your instance variables to private visibility with getter/setters.

If that is not the reason you have to show us more code, e.g. the Chromoson class and how your genes array is structured.

Comment: The getLength method returns the length of the the genes array. I'll attach the Chromosome, Gene and DummmyDatabase in the Question, just 1 second and I'll edit it. Thanks @Pyranja

Comment: Thanks to every1 who helped, got it working, twas where i had the chromosome length set to 19 rather than num of lectures. Thanks u every1

Answer (score 2):

Either `c` or one of your values in `c.genes[i]` is null.

You are trying to do an operation or request a property that is null. So you are getting a `NullPointerException`. If you are using Eclipse or some other IDE of your choice you could debug it and see whats null or post the relevant code so that we can take a guess. Maybe your loop for `i` is flawed.

Comment: If the member `time` is an Integer (rather than an int) it  may be the cause too, if one of the objects are having time set (or intialized by default) to null.

Comment: How would be the best way to show you? I could e-mail it you to see could you take a look? I've been at this all day and just cannot see it, have gotten awful frustrated with it!

Comment: Just gone through the debugger with it and time has a a value set every time, so does c.genes[i], it makes n sense